# How to select/exec column that contains "."?

Tags: kdb

I have a table that contains columns with "." in it:

```
t:([] x:10?`a`b`c; y.z:10?100.0)
```

Appears that this does not work:

```
select/exec y.z from t
```

Also tried these with functional exec:

```
?[`t; (); (); `y.z"]
?[`t; (); (); `$ parse "y.z"]
```

But that also does not work. This notation is working:

```
`y.z xasc t
```

Is there any way to run exec on the column y.z? Also something like this, where I could rename the column:

```
select yz:y.z from t
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of renaming the problem column is using `x xcol y`. This takes `x` as a list of symbols that are the new column names, and a table `y`. This can be used like so:

```
q)exec yz from `x`yz xcol t
39.27524 51.70911 51.59796 40.66642 17.80839 30.177..
```

The problem with trying to select from a column `x.y` is the q will interpret `.` as the [index/apply](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/unclassified/#apply) form.

EDIT:

There is a handy .Q that can be used here! `.Q.id x` is a handy function that "sanitizes" symbols. `x` here can be a a table (or a symbol) and will quickly rename any "bad" columns. It is basically doing everything which we discussed:

```
q).Q.id t
x yz
----------
a 39.27524
b 51.70911
c 51.59796
c 40.66642
b 17.80839
```

Comment: Thanks, yes that would work. Would though not be preferrable, as in my case the real table has ~40 columns and for xcol you have to give the full list of columns until the column that you want to rename. But yes, this definitely helps to solve my problem.

Comment: I feared that might be the case, a quick work around for this would be to use the `except` function to drop the . from any column names, like so
```q)`$except[;"."]each string cols t```
`x`yz
This does require casting it to a string, then going through each column name and dropping the . (or any other unwanted characters) from each column name, then casting it back to a symbol. saves you from writing out all the columns.

Comment: Thanks, yes that's a nice workaround. Using that now. Cheers.

Comment: @Chris You no longer need to list all columns when doing an `xcol` - it now takes a dictionary input representing only the columns you want to rename, e.g. ```((1#`y.z)!1#`yz)xcol t```. However note that this only works as of version V3.6 2018.08.24 and this version 3.6 has some non-back-compatible changes so beware

Answer (score 1):

Having dot in column name is not a good practice and better solution is to fix column names using the approach suggested in other answer.

But if you want to fetch such columns, you can use below solution.

**Select equivalent** ->  First select column from table and then rename it using xcol.

```
q) t:([]x:`a`b`c; y.z:1 2 3)
q) `yz xcol enlist[`y.z]#t
```

```
yz
--
1
2
3
```

**Exec equivalent** -> use indexing:

```
q) t[`y.z]
```

```
1 2 3
```